# What kind of index of papers is behind the search functionality of web applications and services related to the scientific literature?

Tags: literature, indexing

There are many, many websites that include a search function that returns a list of papers matching some keyword: Scirate, Shortscience, Brevy, etc.

Do all these sites run their own crawlers and build up their own index? Or is there a shared index somewhere?

For example, if you go to [shortscience.org/search](http://www.shortscience.org/search), and type in 'computer vision' it comes up with a list of relevant papers. Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Ssrn.com is an open database,  but generally these papers have yet to be peer reviewed.

Comment: Scirate is based on arXiv.

Comment: Of the services that you have listed, only Google Scholar indexes papers. The other services support various "extras" involving academic papers, but aren't really intended as an _index_. Can you clarify what you're asking, and why this information would be useful to you? It might help us give you a better answer.

Comment: For example, if you go to http://www.shortscience.org/search, and type in 'computer vision' it comes up with a list of relevant papers. Where is this data coming from?

Answer (score 3):

There are various APIs that *other* services can use to search assorted indices from other sites

For example, according to the about page of ShortScience.org:

> The search can access all papers in the [DOI](http://www.crossref.org/), [arχiv](https://arxiv.org), [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/), and [Bibsonomy](http://bibsonomy.org/) databases

Some of those (e.g. DBLP) only host bibliographic data; others (e.g. arXiv) host the full text of articles or preprints. Some allow access to their data by API, others make their complete database available for download.

SciRate uses arXiv. Brevy does not seem to have an index; it's just a wiki, and the search function just searches user-submitted content.